# Is unwrapped connection reused?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a spring component like following:

```
@Component
class FooComponent {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void execute() {
        try (SQLServerConnection connection = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(SQLServerConnection.class)) {
        // some logic here with connection
        }
    }   
}
```

I have to unwrap the connection because I'm using some API from Microsoft's JDBC driver (it throws exeption if I'm just passing `dataSource.getConnection()`).

So my question is:
I'm correctly getting the connection in `execute` method? Can that piece of code cause "connection leaks"?

I'm asking this because at some point I saw in logs a error like: `Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException`. (I'm not asking how to solve this error or what it means)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: I'm correctly getting the connection in execute method?

No, the pool returns connection proxies rather than real ones (See [ProxyConnection](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ProxyConnection.java)).
And the proxy's `close` method is "overridden" to return the connection to the pool:

```
if (compare(CLOSE_VAL,method)) {
    if (connection==null) return null; //noop for already closed.
        PooledConnection poolc = this.connection;
        this.connection = null;
        pool.returnConnection(poolc);
        return null;
    } 
}
```

But when you do

```
try (SQLServerConnection connection = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(SQLServerConnection.class))
```

the `close` method called on real connection, not on the proxy. The connection is not returned to the pool and eventually the pool throws `PoolExhaustedException`.

Here is how it can be fixed:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) { // proxy is returned to the pool
    SQLServerConnection c = connection.unwrap(SQLServerConnection.class));
    // Work with SQLServerConnection 
}
```

Also remember that you should leave the unwrapped connection in the same state as you acquired it